# Pycharm's comment / uncomment command

Tags: pycharm

I have difficulties about the comment command.
The comment command is crtl + / but it does not worked.
When I select the code and press crtl+/, it supposes to have '#' at the beginning of the code but it replaces the code to '...'. If I only press crtl+/, it appears '...'.
here is the preference of PyCharm.

[image]

By the way, I am using Windows and PyCharm

print-screen 2:

[image]

Comment: Check in "Settings/Preferences", keymap. Then look for command "Comment with Line Comment". I think `C-/` is not default in all operating system (and preferences)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done what you had said but it still same. please see print-screen 2. Thanks

Comment: Which Operating System? Check again, but in this case click the icon on the right of the search box, and then press `Control-/` (I have various items, but mostly on plug-ins which should not interfere on normal Python code. Note: it works only on file recognized by PyCharm as python (e.g. the pyInstaller .spec file which are python code are not recognized and `Control-/` doesn't work)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't figure it out. Finally, I re-install the anacoda and pycharm and it works right now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I did was the following.

- #### First step

  Open "Pycharm/Settings/Keymap/Main Menu/Code".

  [image: first_step]
- #### Second step

  In the Code go down to "Comment Actions".

  [image: second_step]
- #### Third step

  Inside, you will find "Comment with Line Comment".

  [image: third_step]
- #### Fourth step

  Click there with 2 fingers (I guess right click in Windows) and open the following menu:

  [image: fourth_step]
- #### Fifth step

  Click "Add Keyboard Shortcut" and the following window appears:

  [image: fifth_step]

In the highlighted box type what you want to use. For example I've settled <kbd>⌥C</kbd> and then Accept all windows.

I checked and it works perfect both for Comment as for Uncomment.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings , navigate to keymap , in keymap search

> Comment with Line Comment

Check the corresponding key mapping

Double click for changing

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have done what you had said but it still same. please see print-screen 2. Thanks